# Using date_add function with a timestamp in bigquery results in null for output

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the date_add function with a timestamp in bigquery, but I'm getting 'null' as a result from the output.  I've used date_add successfully before, so I don't understand what the problem is.  Here's a bit of code.

```
SELECT 
userId,
MAX(most_recent_session) most_recent_session,
date_add(MAX(most_recent_session), 24, 'HOUR') as added_a_day,
FROM
(
SELECT
userId,
LAG(time, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY time) as most_recent_session,
LAG(time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY time) as previous_session,
FROM     TABLE_DATE_RANGE(dataset.tablename_, TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, "DAY")), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

GROUP BY
userId,
time
)
)
group by
userID
```

So what I would expect to get out would be three columns, the first containing userId, the second containing a time stamp for that users most recent session, and then a third with 24 hours added on to it. But in the third column instead of getting the value in the 2nd column with 24 hours added on to it, I get 'null'.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to the problem.  You need to wrap the 'most_recent_session' that exists w/ in the outer level of the SQL w/ a USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP function.  That struck me as odd because BQ recognized the field as being a time stamp, but it works.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It looks like DATE_ADD has some weird issues with arguments. 


Works: DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 1, 'HOUR')

Null: DATE_ADD(NOW(), 1, 'HOUR')


Reading the documentation that seems backwards.